# subselect makes complex query really slow

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, query-optimization, multiple-tables

So I want to do the following for a project.

I have 3 tables. First two concern us now (the third is for your better understanding):

```
author {id, name}
authorship {id, id1, id2}
paper {id, title}
```

authorship connects author with paper and authorship.id1 refers to author.id, authorship.id2 refers to paper.id.

What I want to do is make a graph with a node for each author and edge that is determined by the amount of common papers between two authors.

```
w=1 - union_of_common_papers/intersection_of_common_papers
```

So what I have built (with some help from stackoverflow) an sql script that returns all couples of co-authors plus the amount of union and intersection of common papers. After that I will use the data with java. It's the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.name, a2.name, (
  SELECT  concat(count(a.id2), ',', count(DISTINCT a.id2)) 
  FROM authorship a 
  WHERE a.id1=a1.id or a.id1=a2.id) as weight
FROM authorship au1 
INNER JOIN authorship au2 ON au1.id2 = au2.id2 AND au1.id1 <> au2.id1 
INNER JOIN author a1 ON au1.id1 = a1.id 
INNER JOIN author a2 ON au2.id1 = a2.id;
```

this does my job and returns a list like:

```
+-----------------+---------------------+---------+
| name            | name                | weight  |
+-----------------+---------------------+---------+
| Kurt            | Michael             | 161,157 |
| Kurt            | Miron               | 138,134 |
| Kurt            | Manish              | 19,18   |
| Roy             | Gregory             | 21,20   |
| Roy             | Richard             | 74,71   |
....
```

where in weight I can see 2 numbers a,b where b is intersection an b-a is the union of the common papers.

but this takes a lot of time.
And all the overhead is by this extra subselect

```
  (SELECT  concat(count(a.id2), ',', count(DISTINCT a.id2)) 
  FROM authorship a 
  WHERE a.id1=a1.id or a.id1=a2.id) as weight
```

without this line all records (1M+) were returned in less than 2mins.
with this line 50 records need more than 1.5mins

I use mysql on linux through command line

Any ideas how I can optimize it?

- author has ~130,000 records
- authorship ~1,300,000 records
- query should return ~1,200,000 records

This is what explain returns for this query. don't know how to use it.

```
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type   | possible_keys       | key       | key_len | ref          | rows    | Extra           |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a1    | ALL    | PRIMARY             | NULL      | NULL    | NULL         |  124768 | Using temporary |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | au1   | ref    | NewIndex1,NewIndex2 | NewIndex1 | 5       | dblp.a1.ID   |       4 | Using where     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | au2   | ref    | NewIndex1,NewIndex2 | NewIndex2 | 5       | dblp.au1.id2 |       1 | Using where     |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | a2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY             | PRIMARY   | 4       | dblp.au2.id1 |       1 |                 |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | a     | ALL    | NewIndex1           | NULL      | NULL    | NULL         | 1268557 | Using where     |
+----+--------------------+-------+--------+---------------------+-----------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get your data directly from the joins in the outer query.

You can count the number of papers in common by counting the distinct `id2` where that is the same for both authors.

You can count the total number of papers as the number of distinct papers for each author minus the ones in common (because otherwise, these would be counted twice):

```
SELECT a1.name, a2.name,
       COUNT(distinct case when au1.id2 = au2.id2 then au1.id2 end) as CommonPapers,
       COUNT(distinct au1.id2) + COUNT(distinct au2.id2) - COUNT(distinct case when au1.id2 = au2.id2 then au1.id2 end) as TotalPapers
FROM authorship au1 INNER JOIN
     authorship au2
     ON au1.id2 = au2.id2 AND au1.id1 <> au2.id1 INNER JOIN
     author a1
     ON au1.id1 = a1.id INNER JOIN
     author a2
     ON au2.id1 = a2.id
group by a1.name, a2.name;
```

In your data structure, `id1` and `id2` are lousy names.  Have you considered something like `idauthor` and `idpaper` or something like that?

The above query counts the intersection correctly, but not the total, because of the initial inner join.  one way around this is a `full outer join`, but that is not allowed in MySQL.  We can do this with additional subqueries:

```
SELECT a1.name, a2.name,
       COUNT(distinct case when au1.id2 = au2.id2 then au1.id2 end) as CommonPapers,
       (ap1.NumPapers + ap2.NumPapers - COUNT(distinct case when au1.id2 = au2.id2 then au1.id2 end)
       ) as TotalPapers
FROM authorship au1 INNER JOIN
     authorship au2
     ON au1.id2 = au2.id2 AND au1.id1 <> au2.id1 INNER JOIN
     author a1
     ON au1.id1 = a1.id INNER JOIN
     author a2
     ON au2.id1 = a2.id inner join
     (select au.id1, count(*) as numpapers
      from authorship au
     ) ap1
     on ap1.id1 = au1.id1 inner join
     (select au.id1, count(*) as numpapers
      from authorship au
     ) ap2
     on ap2.id1 = au2.id1 inner join
group by a1.name, a2.name;
```

Comment: you're totally right about the ids names. I'm checking now your suggestion.

Comment: no it doesn't really work. seems like running forever. And I have set limit to 5.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `author(id)` and `authorship(id2, id1)`?  They might help.  You do have a lot of rows of data.  If one of those papers has 1000 authors, then the data really multiplies.

Comment: the second suggestion with full join workaround returns empty set.

Comment: thanks the first one runs in really short time ~5mins. It bothers me that I cannot use the distinct and I have to group by. As for the common COUNT(distinct au1.id2) is the same as COUNT(distinct au2.id2) same as total common papers. Thanks a lot again, I will figure the rest on my own.